# Excel Programming VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to display YES or NO from the given data of EXCEL . I have tried to write program . But i cant find the solution . It displays YES only not NO even if output should be NO . Please Help me with this program .

I have to check the data of whole column of C ( data is from number 2 to 1439 of the column). If the data is >=0.003 , It should display NO else it should display Yes.

CODE:

```
' Declare  array
Dim arrMarks(0 To 1437) As Double
 Sub ArrayLoops()

    ' Fill the array with numbers
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(arrMarks) To UBound(arrMarks)
        arrMarks(i) = Range("C2:C1439").Select
        Next i


    ' Using If statement

    For i = LBound(arrMarks) To UBound(arrMarks)
    If arrMarks(i) >= 0.003 Then
    MsgBox ("NO")
    Else
    End If

    Next i
    MsgBox ("YES")

End Sub
```

Comment: is using the `msgbox` sufficient enough for you?

Comment: Do you want to only display "No" once?

Comment: Isn't this something that would better left to an [excel-formula] or [conditional formatting]?

Answer (score 1):

Your "YES" was outside of both the loop and the test, so that is why you get it every time! ;)

Look at the way to fill an array directly from a range with `.Value` :

```
Sub ArrayLoops()
'Declare  array
Dim arrMarks()
Dim i As Integer
'Fill the array with range
arrMarks = Range("C2:C1439").Value

'Using If statement
For i = LBound(arrMarks, 1) To UBound(arrMarks, 1)
    If arrMarks(i, 1) >= 0.003 Then
        MsgBox ("NO")
    Else
        MsgBox ("YES")
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But when i run the same code as yours it there was 'Run time Error 13': Type Mismatch. I dont know what it is and how to get rid of it . Can you please help me !

Comment: When you have an error, plz also specify on which line! ;) My guess is that it is on the `arrMarks =  ...` line, try the edit! ;)

Comment: It should be highlighted in yellow! ;)

Comment: It only says type Mismatch . There is no yellow line shown :(

Comment: If you have a type mismatch, it would suggest that the data has a different type in a cell. Depends on your error handling and whats calling the code when debugging. Try in the VBIDE selecting Tools:Options:General: Break On All Errors. That should stop exactly at the error. Don't forget to switch it back it its original setting though!

Comment: I have data like 0.001 Hz/s, 0.002 Hz/s  in that column in my excel sheet . I found that there is error with the statement: ( If arrMarks(i) >= 0.003 Then ) but i dont know how to correct it !!!!

Comment: @adityalamichhane : Plz lets us know if this work fine and take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour to know how SO (and community) works!

Comment: @R3uK , would't you need to `redim arrMarks(1 to 1439)` , before setting its value ? , btw dont forget its a 2 dimension array :  `If arrMarks(i,1) >= 0.003 Then` , (don't forget the `,1`)

Comment: to know wiwh line errors hit DEBUG when it errors, not END.

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier : You don't need to redim before setting value when you use `Range.Value`. But thx for your remarks, I already fixed this in a previous edit but got no news from the OP since! ;)

Comment: Brilliant ! The code Worked perfectly . Thank you very much.